# how to update opencv manager?

Tags: opencv, android

does someone know how to install opencv manager higher than 3.0.0 version on android emulator ?! the only version available on play store or other apk web sites is 3.0.0
 I'm using android studio emulator.

Comment: Why you need a higher version of OpenCV manager. As your app containing opencv can also run without that on the emulator.

Comment: I'm using multiplication of matrix in my algorithm in RGB image i get this bug erroe libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x16 in tid 15716 (y.myapplication), i found tuto that ask to install higher opencv manager version in hope to sove it